# 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Mapped Superclass'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA in my project. I would like to keep track of `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` when an entity is saved or updated to know which user does that activity. But the issue I am facing is I have 2 different types of users. Those are `SysUser` and `RefUser`. Both of the user types have permission to do CRUD operations in any entity.

And another thing is I have seen the most examples persisting `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` as String fields. But the issue is when retrieving data from the database they are retrieving as User Ids (String values). I need to store user Ids as Strings, but when retrieving it should come the user's all details like user's id, name, gender etc.

```
public class Record extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<T> {

    @CreatedBy
    protected T createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected T lastModifiedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

Also I have a common class annotated with `@MappedSuperClass` that extended by `SysUser` and `RefUser`. But when I am trying to add that common class as a filed like the following it says

> 'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Mapped Superclass'

```
private CommonEntity crUsr;
private CommonEntity upUsr;
```

So how can I achieve this? Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can do one thing here. Create a common class named `User` put all the common properties from `SysUser` and `RefUser` in that class. Then you can extend that in both the class and keep only distinct fields in the Child classes. This way any user do the operation will belong to `User` Class.

After that you can do something like this in your Class:

```
public class Record extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<User> {

@CreatedBy
protected User createdBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
protected Date createdDate;

@LastModifiedBy
protected T lastModifiedBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
protected Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I have a common class but that is an abstract class and annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`. So when adding it as a field it says `Basic' attribute type should not be 'Mapped Superclass' `. Do you know a solution?

Comment: You can use the Adapter pattern in that case. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Will you be able to show me an example applying to this issue?